# Little problem with HTML form and input tags and with PHP get method (Warning: Undefined array key)

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I am trying to get some basic information from the user -

```
<body>
  <form action = "index.php" method="get">
    Name: <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Age: <input type="number" name="age">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <br>
  Your name is <?php echo $_GET["username"] ?>
  <br>
  Your age is <?php echo $_GET["age"] ?>
 </body>
```

This code is functional, but when I look to the browser prior to filling in the name and age, there is kind of a glitch, which can be seen underneath the submit button.

```
Your name is
Warning: Undefined array key "username" in path\index.php on line 15

Your age is
Warning: Undefined array key "age" in path\index.php on line 17
```

However, when I enter in some information, then that error disappears, but it would be nice, if it was not there in the first place.

Could anybody give me any advice on how to fix this bug?

Comment: Please check the second section, titled "Notice: Undefined index / Undefined offset / Warning: Undefined array key" of the accepted answer. You need to check with `isset` before printing it.

Comment: e.g. `<?php if(isset($_GET["username"])) {echo $_GET["username"];} ?>`

Comment: Hey, thanks for Your contribution. I think that the question, which you have mentioned, does contain the solution, but it was kind of hidden among the other suggestions, thus I would be glad, if my question would not be closed, because here I can at least see it at the first sight, because I am using SO as kind of a documentation of my problems, which I have encountered along the various programming ways. In any case I am thankful for this hint. That question also contains a link to the PHP manual as well and it might really be worth reading.

Comment: There is no need to add "(Solved) :-)" to your title; the system will automatically show the question as solved since you have press the checkmark next to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your echo under `isset()` condition. It will prevent the execution of the code if `$_GET["username"]` is not set or in other words, it will prevent the display if the form is not submitted(like on page load)

```
if(isset($_GET["username"])){
   echo $_GET["username"];
 }
```

Comment: Greetings, thanks for Your explanation. Now I understand it better and it makes more sense to me. This is a valuable lesson for me. I have made a modification to the code, which will show the "Your name is " and "Your age is " parts visible after the insertion of these information or in other words it will be visible after that $_GET[""] fields will be set.